# Deficienting rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Dear friends

Let ‎$\bf{C}‎$‎ be a ‎$m \times n‎$ ‎matrix, where its elements are drawn randomly from a continious distribution, and its rank is ‎$\min (m, n)$‎ with probability one. For ‎decreasing the rank of $\bf{C}$ to ‎$d‎$‎, where ‎$‎d \le \min(n,m) $; how many elements of ‎$\bf{C}$ should be changed (designed).

For example, ${\bf{A}}$ is a 2-by-2 matrix with random generated elements as follows: 
A=[1, 2; 3, 4]
if I wish to decrease its rank to one, it is necessary to change one of the elements of A, as follows:
A_new=[1.5 2; 3 4]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The answer is clear when $d=\min(m,n)$ (almost surely no need to change any entry) or $d=\min(m,n)-1$ ($\max(m,n)-d$ entries are almost surely enough and minimum). For smaller $d$, the problem seems difficult.